# SQL Query Results where Join has NULL results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm wondering if you can help - I've got an SQL Query (SQLServer) which i've created, although some results are not being shown and i think its due to NULL results on some joins. For example, i know some of the joins will be using NULL results as 100.resp_unit_no may well be NULL aswell as 100.employee_no.

The query so far is:

```
select 
058.DESCRIPTION "IRU",
111.job_ref "Job Reference",
117.DESCRIPTION "Status",
108.STATUS "Fixed?",
105.DESCRIPTION "Job Type",
111.POSTCODE "Postcode",
111.site_id "Site ID",
108.CONTRACT_START "Contract Earliest",
108.CONTRACT_COMPLETION "Contract Latest",
108.BOOKED_DURATION "Planned Duration (mins)",
111.IMPORTANCE "Importance",
111.CUSTOMER_NAME "Customer Name",
100.expected_start "Expected Start",
100.expected_end "Expected End",
210.NAME "Employee",
111.ON_HOLD "On Hold?"
FROM 
111_JOBS 111,
108_JOB_DETAILS 108,
058_RESPONSIBILITY_UNITS 058,
100_ACTIVITIES 100,
105_ACTIVITY_TYPES 105,
210_EMPLOYEES 210,
117_STATUS_DESCRIPTIONS 117
where 111.JOB_NO=108.JOB_NO
AND 111.JOB_NO=100.JOB_NO
AND 100.RESP_UNIT_NO=058.RESP_UNIT_NO
AND 111.JOB_TYPE=105.ACTIVITY_TYPE
AND 210.EMPLOYEE_NO=100.EMPLOYEE_NO
AND 117.STATUS=100.ACTIVITY_STATUS
order by IRU, Employee, EXPECTED_START;
```

I think i need a right outer join, but i cant quite get the structure correct...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use numbers as aliases! And read about joins and proper join syntax here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html Does your query even run?

Comment: It does run - Comes back with the results apart from the once where the employee_no and resp_unit_no are null..
I do have characters in front of the numbers - Its just my company name and i don't really want to send that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your query to use ANSI-92 explicit join syntax rather than the ANSI-89 syntax that you are using (which is, as the names suggest over 20 years out of dates) then you query will become much easier to manipulate:

```
SELECT  058.DESCRIPTION "IRU",
        111.job_ref "Job Reference",
        117.DESCRIPTION "Status",
        108.STATUS "Fixed?",
        105.DESCRIPTION "Job Type",
        111.POSTCODE "Postcode",
        111.site_id "Site ID",
        108.CONTRACT_START "Contract Earliest",
        108.CONTRACT_COMPLETION "Contract Latest",
        108.BOOKED_DURATION "Planned Duration (mins)",
        111.IMPORTANCE "Importance",
        111.CUSTOMER_NAME "Customer Name",
        100.expected_start "Expected Start",
        100.expected_end "Expected End",
        210.NAME "Employee",
        111.ON_HOLD "On Hold?"
FROM    111_JOBS 111
        INNER JOIN 108_JOB_DETAILS 108
            ON 111.JOB_NO = 108.JOB_NO
        INNER JOIN 100_ACTIVITIES 100
            ON 111.JOB_NO = 100.JOB_NO
        LEFT JOIN 058_RESPONSIBILITY_UNITS 058          
            100.RESP_UNIT_NO = 058.RESP_UNIT_NO
        LEFT JOIN 105_ACTIVITY_TYPES 105
            ON 111.JOB_TYPE = 105.ACTIVITY_TYPE
        LEFT JOIN 210_EMPLOYEES 210
            ON 210.EMPLOYEE_NO = 100.EMPLOYEE_NO
        LEFT JOIN 117_STATUS_DESCRIPTIONS 117
            ON 117.STATUS = 100.ACTIVITY_STATUS
ORDER BY IRU, Employee, EXPECTED_START;
```

Now, without knowing what columns may be null, I don't know which joins to change from `INNER` to `LEFT`, so I have only changed a few of them, but you should be able to change a few more as needed.

[Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has written a [good article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), with even more reasons to switch to the newer join syntax.

Comment: Is this a COBOL program converted to a SQL Server database?  I have not seen numbers at the start of a variable since Y2K!  Personally, I like keeping aliases small such as JOBDET as [Job_Details].  Numbers are very hard to remember.

Comment: I think it is pseudo code, the comment on the question seems to suggest part of the table name and alias have been removed. I'd agree with the difficulty to remember,  but there could be a good reason for it (I can't think of one though)

Comment: Thanks Gareth - Your update sorted it.. I'd used that before but I just couldn't get my head around it as i was taught the old fashion way but i need to update.
Yes i'd removed the alias names as we have everything prefixed with company ID which i didn't want to publish. Just did a search/replace :)